# How to do conditional compilation with Zig?

Tags: compilation, compile-time, conditional-compilation, build-system, zig

For example, I can add definitions for C/C++ preprocessor with CMake

```
add_definitions(-DFOO -DBAR ...)
```

and then I can use them for conditional compilation

```c
#ifdef FOO
   code ...
#endif

#ifdef BAR
   code ...
#endif
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with Zig and its build system using compilation arguments or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar using the build system. This requires some boilerplate code to do the option handling. Following the tutorial on https://zig.news/xq/zig-build-explained-part-1-59lf for the build system and https://ziggit.dev/t/custom-build-options/138/8 for the option handling:

1. Create a separate file called `build.zig` that contains a function `build()`:

```c
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) !void {
    const build_options = b.addOptions();
    // add command line flag
    // and set default value
    build_options.addOption(bool, "sideways", b.option(bool, "sideways", "print sideways") orelse false);

    // set executable name and source code
    const exe = b.addExecutable("hello", "hello.zig");
    exe.addOptions("build_options", build_options);
    // compile and copy to zig-out/bin
    exe.install();
}
```

2. Use the option for conditional compilation in a separate file `hello.zig` using `@import("build_options")`:

```c
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const print_sideways = @import("build_options").sideways;
    const stdout = std.io.getStdOut().writer();
    if (print_sideways) {
       try stdout.print("Sideways Hello, {s}!\n", .{"world"});
    } else {
       try stdout.print("Regular Hello, {s}!\n", .{"world"});
    }
}
```

3. Compile with:

```
zig build -Dsideways=true
```

4. Executing `zig-out/bin/hello` gives the following output:

```
Sideways Hello, world!
```